# photon unity foreach loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

really simple question really

how do i get this loop to show all players because its only showing my player.
as you can see i tried starting a new line.

when i do the samestatment except playerlist i use otherlist it returns another player so why isnt the player list showing everyone :S

```
void openCloseScore()
{
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Tab)) 
    {
        ScoreBoard.SetActive (true);
        foreach(PhotonPlayer player in PhotonNetwork.playerList) 
        {
            ScoreboardTxt.text = "\r\nPlayerName:  " + player.ToString();
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        ScoreBoard.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Every time you iterate through your foreach loop, ScoreboardTxt.text is being replaced. So the final item in PhotonNetwork.playerList will always show up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you should use `+=` to concatenate all the players' data.

```
ScoreboardTxt.text += "\r\nPlayerName:  " + player.ToString();
```

Without the `+=` `ScoreboardTxt.text` will only contain data about the last player.

Comment: thanks soo much now i face a bigger problem the forloop is repeating in the text

Comment: actually fixed in tab up i wipe the text file

Answer (score 0):

You're only showing the last player, not yours.
You should add to the Text property, not repalce it.

```
void openCloseScore(){
  if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Tab)) {
      ScoreBoard.SetActive (true);
      foreach(PhotonPlayer player in PhotonNetwork.playerList) {
          //  ... change next line ...
          ScoreboardTxt.text += "\r\nPlayerName:  " + player.ToString(); // <------- change = to += in this line
    }
  } else {
    ScoreBoard.SetActive (false);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I rather suggest use `StringBuilder` for such purpose. This will reduce allocation and CPU usage.

```cs
void openCloseScore(){
  if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Tab)) {
      ScoreBoard.SetActive (true);
      var str = new StringBuiler();
      foreach(PhotonPlayer player in PhotonNetwork.playerList) {
          str.AppendLine($"PlayerName: {player.ToString()}";
      }
      ScoreboardTxt.text = str.ToString();
  } else {
    ScoreBoard.SetActive (false);
  }
}
```

In the end I suggest you to create class for each player entity. And spawn items to scoreboard when player join, destroy when leaves.